# How to use JavaScript variable in CSS style?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually I want something like that:

```
var color = #000;

$(".div").find("li").css({"border-left": '5px solid [`I want to add this variable (color) here`]});
```

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: simple string concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var color = "#00f";
$("#button").click(function(){
  $("div").css({"border": "5px solid " + color});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Add Border</button>
<div>Hi, I am a div</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can use ES6 then a template literal is a good choice here. It uses backticks instead of other types of quotes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```
var color = "#000"; //change this to be a string as @Nikos mentioned

$(".div").find("li").css({"border-left": `5px solid  ${color}`});
```

Comment: Looks like you beat me by 4 seconds, great minds :)

Comment: color should be a string though,

Comment: Good point.  Ill update

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: Did you see the note about your `var color = #000` missing quotes?

Comment: No i didn't see this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".div").find("li").css({"border-left": `5px solid ${color}`});
```